# Level "?" or null in R

Tags: r, null, levels

I got a binomial variable and this is the values it takes:

`[1] 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 0 0 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 0 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 1`

In spite of that, it says these are the levels where one of them is "?" and I don't understand why

`Levels:  ? 0 1`

Thanks!!

Reply to your comments:
First of all, sorry for the little info, its my first post in stackoverflow. I did what you say, here it is what it appears.

```
> unique(DatosHue$nidoExitosoPue)
[1] 1 0
Levels:  ? 0 1
> dput(DatosHue$nidoExitosoPue)
structure(c(4L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 
3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L), .Label = c("", "?", "0", "1"), class = "factor")
> unique(DatosHue$nidoExitosoPue)
[1] 1 0
Levels:  ? 0 1
> levels(DatosHue$nidoExitosoPue)
[1] ""  "?" "0" "1"
> droplevels(DatosHue$nidoExitosoPue)
 [1] 1 1 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
[53] 1 1 0 1 1 0 0 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 0 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 1
Levels: 0 1
> levels(DatosHue$nidoExitosoPue)
[1] ""  "?" "0" "1"
```

Thanks!!

Comment: try `droplevels`

Comment: I'd try `unique()` to see what shows up

Comment: `unique` wont show that  may need `levels(v1)`

Comment: `unique` is exactly the correct function. maybe someone used `?` to indicate missing data, you can custom strings to indicate `NA`s when you import data, for example `read.csv(..., na_strings = c('NA', '?'))` or `readxl::read_excel(..., na = c('NA', '?'))`

Comment: please make sur eto provide a reproducible example. all you show is output of a certain object, it would be great to see what is the actual object is. use dput() command to obtain a reproducible exanple

Comment: Thanks! I tried what you did, I reedited the post to show you. Still doesnt work, I dont understand why. Thanks again!

Comment: Would you be able to add to the examples what command you run to get it?